# performing function trace forward in Windbg

Tags: windows, windbg

I wanted to ask if there is any option to perform function tracing like **ltrace** command does using **Windbg** debugger of Windows that will show all functions that are being executed from specific break point

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know Linux `ltrace`, but the description of it looks like you might be searching for the WinDbg command [`wt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/wt--trace-and-watch-data-).

I think it inserts a breakpoint (INT3, opcode `0xCC`) at the specified end address, so please make sure that the end address is correct. Otherwise you might end up with a `0xCC` somewhere in your data.

The output is potentially long, so a [`.logopen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-logopen--open-log-file-) is certainly helpful.